# Routing to dynamic subdomain does not work laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, apache, routes, subdomain

Subdomain does not work. Did I set up DNS incorrectly? When i visit page - **Connection attempt failed**.

My **httpd.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/blog
</VirtualHost>
```

**hosts** file

```
127.0.0.1   example.com
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
  #dd(request()->cookie());
  return view('home.home');
})->name('home');

Route::domain('{username}.'.env('SESSION_DOMAIN'))->group(function () {
  Route::get('/', [PostController::class,'getAllPosts'])
  ->name('blog');
});
```

in **.env**

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=example.com
```